# Simplify the expression of $ T^+$ for an unbounded operator $T$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-norms, unbounded-operators

For a negative unbounded operator $T$, what equals the operator 
$$ T^+ =  \left[\frac{1}{2}(|T| + T) \right]^{**},$$
where $|T|= (T^2)^{1/2}$ and $A^{**} $ is the minimal closed extension of an operator $A$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what does ** mean?

Comment: $A^{**}$ is the minimal closed extension of an operator $A$

Answer (score 2):

The adjective "negative" implies that you have an operator on a Hilbert space.  It then follows from the spectral theorem for unbounded operators that your expression is simply the zero operator.  The double star operation ensures that its domain is the whole space, not just that of $T$.

Comment: The graph of the algebraic sum is the set $(x,0)$  with $x$ in the domain of $T$. This is not closed, so this sum is not self-adjoint.  Its closure is the graph of the  zero operator as I stated in my answer.